# Did DKOM trigger PatchGuard on x64 Windows?

Tags: windows, kernel

DKOM can be used to hide processes and drivers. It works well on x86 system. However, there are PatchGuard on x64 system. Can PatchGuard detect DKOM?

Comment: There are claims that this is undocumented... http://www.kernelmode.info/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=2221 I'm not sure if you'll find an answer other than by testing yourself.